# repeat or iterate the tests in pytest

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I have written a test which works fine and would like to repeat same test for different values.

Example: Test1 for value as "Farnell",

2nd test for value as "Tango",

3rd test for "Bravo" and so on

Could you help me to repeat the tests. Thank you

```
def test_supplier_Farnell(setup):
        test_login_infor(setup)
        # time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Supplier Sites").click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        **driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Farnell").click()**
        time.sleep(0.5)
        driver.switch_to.frame("bottomframe")
        driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//frame[@name='Header']"))
        bodyText = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text
```

Comment: [How to parametrize fixtures and test functions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/parametrize.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only thing you are changing is the string you are searching for ("Farnell", "Tango", etc.) then you can add that string as an argument to your test and pass a different argument each time you call it.

```
test_strings = ["Farnell", "Tango", "Bravo"]
def test_supplier(setup, test_string):
        test_login_infor(setup)
        # time.sleep(2)
        driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "Supplier Sites").click()
        time.sleep(0.5)
        **driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, test_string).click()**
        time.sleep(0.5)
        driver.switch_to.frame("bottomframe")
        driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//frame[@name='Header']"))
        bodyText = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text

for test_string in test_strings:
    test_supplier(setup, test_string)
```